# Converter HTML para Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Existe uma forma simples e rápida de migrar um site estático em `HTML` para `Wordpress` ?
Somente o HTML como tema para WP

Comment: No caso seria só o layout para criar um tema ou o conteúdo junto? Porque o WP trabalha com PHP e banco de dados

Comment: Somente o layout. Precisava importar o HTML como um tema do WP

Comment: Com o html pronto fica muito mais fácil, é apenas uma questão de converter as partes estáticas para dinâmicas, por exemplo, tem uma área que repete itens como artigos ou um blog, basta colocar a estrutura do arquivo em um loop e  assim por diante, o Chris Coyer tem um vídeo só sobre isso onde ele passa um HTML e CSS para tema do WP -> http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/73-wordpress-theme/ outro lugar muito bom é o codex do WP que tem referência das funções http://codex.wordpress.org/.

Answer (score -4):

Caso queiras apenas o tema em **HTML** podes usar o seguinte programa: **HTTRACK**. Caso queiras todas as funções, acho que não é possivel.