# É possível converter um template HTML em WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Recentemente comprei um template em um certo site, e não percebi que era HTML, e não o que eu preciso, que é tema para Wordpress. Eles não trocam. É possível converter?

Comment: Amigo, mas o wordpress também usa HTML. O Wordpress é um CMS(https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_conte%C3%BAdo).Agora a partir do código HTML, vc pode criar um template para o wordpress, aí lhe aconselho a dar uma "particionada" na sua pergunta e incluir a tag wordpress

Comment: Sim. Mas vai dar um pouco de trabalho. Possível duplicata de: [Converter HTML para Wordpress](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49121/70)

Comment: Márcio me diz uma coisa, você tem algum conhecimento em php ? Estou perguntando, pq o wordpress é todo(ou quase) em php, e uma das tarefas é ler html, no entanto este CMS é configurado de modo hierárquico e coisa e talz... O que quero dizer é que não é simples, mas acredito que se tiver um conhecimento básico de php ou programação, você pode começar por como criar um template PHP Wordpress, que é até simples, mas tudo depende da complexidade do template (site) que tenha, Um sistema pronto click e converta, eu ainda não vi, mas deve ter tmb...

Comment: Olá amigo. Obrigado por responder. Meu conhecimento em php é muito pouco, pois abandonei o curso de webdesigner já a algum tempo pela enrolação e custo, e me adptei ao uso do wp e seus templates pela "facilidade" de manipulação com seus plugins e etc...já quase prontos. Tem me atendido bem. Ainda não faço trabalhos externos, á não ser pra auxiliar um amigo. O template é bem complexo, pois pra clinica que estamos montando , vai ter chat, Agenda online entre outros...Vou testar uma copia do tema e ver o que consigo fazer. Agradeço pela atenção MagicHat

Comment: Não sei se pode postar esses links aqui e já peço desculpas, Mas Seguem 2 links do thema.

Comment: @MarcioNícoli qual a linguagem utilizada nesse sistema que comprou ? Por ter chat e ser um sisteminha mais complexo, imagino que tenha uma linguagem back-end, tipo um php ?

Comment: Comprei esse   >>>>>https://themeforest.net/item/clinico-responsive-medical-and-health-template/7112924?s_rank=2                                                  Achando que fosse o mesmo >>>>>>>>>>>>>>  https://themeforest.net/item/clinico-responsive-medical-and-health-template/7112924?s_rank=2

Comment: MagicHat, acha que da pra mexer no código e usar no Wp?  Se não der vou deixar ele no hd e usar um free até adquirir.

Comment: Mano pelo que vi, vc comprou um por $5 e a versão wp é $17, uma diferença de $12,  se você sabe perfeitamente fazer essa conversão entre um template normal para um template wp, com certeza vai sair mais caro a migração do que $12, se você não faz ideia de como fazer... Usa um free.. e vai fazendo a migração pouco a pouco em paralelo.

Comment: Não meu Parceiro, comprei o de $17, mais 6 meses de suporte,$5.  Mas o template pra Wp é $59. Tentei negociar e pagar a diferença, mas ñ obtive resposta. Bom, Foi O que pensei. Vlw Pela moral.  Abs

Comment: Obrigado Tbm ao Bacco.